# Anchor point of x,y in JavaFX nodes

Tags: graphics, 2d, javafx

Some sprite applications (namely [pulpcore](http://www.interactivepulp.com/pulpcore/)) allows you to define an anchor point for an object.

For example if the anchor point of a rectangle is `0,0` and it's coordinates are `x:0,y:0` the top left point of the rectangle would be displayed on the top left point of the screen.

If however the anchor point of the rectangle is `50,50` and it's size is `100x100`, the middle of the rectangle would be placed at `0,0` and only it's bottom-right part would be displayed.

Is there a similar property in JavaFX? Is there an easy way to implement this (can you bind the `x` and the `y` coordinates of a JavaFX node to its own height and width?)?

When I bind the `x,y` coordinates to `boundsInLocal/Parent.width` I get a runtime exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The origin for a Rectangle is upper left as you say. 
You have 2 options for positioning the node. You can use either layoutX and layoutY.
var rect = Rectangle {
     layoutX: 50
     layoutY: 50
     widht: 100
     height: 100
}

or translateX and translateY

var rect = Rectangle {
     translateX: 50
     translateY: 50
     widht: 100
     height: 100
}
The main purpose of using both layoutX/Y and translateX/Y, is that translateX/Y is intended to be changeable whereas layoutX/Y is meant for initial positioning. For example, you can change translateX/Y in an animation while the original position is remembered in layoutX/Y. The ultimate location will always be layoutX+ translateX and layoutY + translateY.

To shift the origin to the center point (50,50) use a negative translate.
var rect = Rectangle {
     translateX: -50
     translateY: -50
     widht: 100
     height: 100
}

Some shapes are not based on upper left origin. For example, Circle uses centerX and centerY.

Comment: Not good enough. I want to bind X,Y to the width of the current node.

Comment: so you could do:

var rect: Rectangle = Rectangle{ x: bind rect.width y: bind rect.height };

or preferably

var rect: Rectangle = Rectangle{ layoutX: bind rect.width layoutY: bind rect.height };

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, x and y has been removed from Node. You have to use layoutX/Y or translateX/Y. So you could do Rectangle { layoutX: bind rect.layoutBounds.width }.